# what does parent play in $mddialog?

Tags: angularjs

While using $mddialog I saw  a parent key in $mddialog, what role does it play??

```
        $mdDialog.show({
           controller: DialogController,
           templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
           parent: angular.element(document.body),
           targetEvent: ev,
           clickOutsideToClose:true,
           fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen 
           })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parent is the element in the DOM that the dialog's html is added to.

In your case, the Dialog's HTML content will be a direct child of the document body, i.e, a direct child of the body tag.